# Remove dash from the HTML element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I want to remove **—** from the form below.

```
<form id="product-search" action="" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="min_price" value="" placeholder="Min">
   — 
   <input type="text" name="max_price" value="" placeholder="Max" >
</form>
```

I tried below jQuery code, but cannot make it work?

```
$('#product-search').removeByContent('—');​
```

But this doesn't work. Please any help?

Comment: What is `removeByContent`, it doesn't seem to be a jQuery function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property that select sibling text after element.

```js
$("#product-search input:first")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="product-search" action="" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="min_price" value="" placeholder="Min">
   — 
   <input type="text" name="max_price" value="" placeholder="Max" >
</form>
```